# Delay or Pause Powershell command output

Tags: powershell

I am new to PowerShell, and I wanted to know if what I'm trying to do is possible.

The output of `netstat` is a lot and I need to scroll down to visualize it.

I was wondering if there is a way to delay the rate at which the output is printed on the shell, or maybe pause the command for a bit and then resume it. Every option I find pauses the script after the execution of the previous command; not mid-execution.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Add `| more` to the end of the `netstat` command and the output will pause after the first screenful.

Comment: I like to use `| Out-GridView` in Windows Powershell for large output. You can use simple filters and sort the output without much effort.